# Config-file-provider-plugin: Create new config in multipipeline config folder in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am using a multibranch pipeline and would like to have branch specific configs. I currently have a default config which I would like to clone to a config with ID "${BRANCH_NAME}_config". I am using default jenkins file plugin so there is no jenkins code in the repository and using Config-file-provider-plugin for the config file handling and have made some progress.

I currently have the ability to create a global config with the following code:

```
configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'DEFAULT_JSON_CONFIG', variable: 'default_config_content')]) {
    def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
    def provider = instance.getExtensionList('org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.json.JsonConfig$JsonConfigProvider')[0]
    def config = new org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.json.JsonConfig("${BRANCH_NAME}_config", "Config for ${BRANCH_NAME}", "Branch config ${BRANCH_NAME}", "$default_config_content")
    provider.save(config)
}
```

But need to create it in the job's (multipipeline) config folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement this with help from [JENKINS-56305](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56305)

```
def folder = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('jobName');
def action = folder.getAction(org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.folder.FolderConfigFileAction.class);
def store = action.getStore();
def config = new org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.json.JsonConfig("XXXX_config", "Config for XXXX", "Branch config XXXX", "{A:B}");
// save the new config
store.save(config);
// get the new config
def jsonConfig = store.getById("XXXX_config");
// remove the config
store.remove("XXXX_config");
```